# Динамическое выделение памяти под массивы char C++

Tags: c++

Хочу создать динамический массив у̶к̶а̶з̶а̶т̶е̶л̶е̶й̶  на строки char без использования string и vector и самостоятельно их заполнить, а затем вывести их на экран. Недавно начал изучать плюсы и захотелось именно таким образом попробовать создать массив со строками.

```
#include <iostream>
const int size = 4;

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    system("cls");
    char* pt = new char[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Введите строку: " << std::endl;
        std::cin.getline(pt+i, 20);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Строка: "<< (pt+i) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Но, к сожалению, он не выводит на экран полностью отдельные строки. Подскажите, где ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *"Хочу создать динамический массив указателей"* - ¿а почему же не создаете?

Comment: А разве char* pt = new char[size]; не создаёт массив на char из 4 указателей?

Comment: Нет, он создает массив на size штук *просто char*

Comment: `char** pt = ...`

Comment: Понял! А как корректно тогда заполнить эти 4 массива, чтобы можно было их отобразить?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, вы имеете ввиду, что было на скрине? Простите, не очень понял.

Comment: у вас вроде всего одна картинка приложена к вопросу. а на этой картинке при желании можно разобрать какой-то текст. вот про то, что данный текст лучше прилагать именно как текст, и написан совет в моём предыдущем комментарии.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
char** pt = new char*[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    char buf[100];
    std::cout << "Введите строку: " << std::endl;
    std::cin.getline(buf,100);
    pt[i] = new char[strlen(buf)+1];
    strcpy(pt[i],buf);
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "Строка: "<< pt[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! Скажите, а можно ли схоже сделать не с массивом указателей, а просто с массивом элементов char с количеством size и также с помощью new? По неопытности я предположил, что   
char* pt = new char[size]; означает массив указателей.

Comment: Не очень понимаю, что вы хотите, потому и ответить не могу...

Comment: Как я понял, char* pt = new char[size] - это выделение памяти под массив из 4 строк char. Я хотел, используя эту строку, выделить память и самостоятельно заполнить её введёнными мной словами, и отобразить их на экране. Но по незнанию воспринял строку " char* pt = new char[size] " как выделение памяти под массив указателей на char и указал это в формулировке 
 вопроса. В действительности, как меня тут поправили, это просто выделение памяти на массив из 4 строк char. Вот я думаю, как можно решить свой вопрос  через char* pt = new char[size]

Comment: @Bizzarro "это выделение памяти под массив из 4" символов

Comment: @Igor, Господи...Игорь, спасибо большое! no comments...